# Webhook option disappeared

Tags: gitlab

I've been using Gitlab Community edition for a while now. Overall it was working great. But since last Friday I noticed webhooks are no longer being send out from the server.

When logging in as root on the gitlab web interface I can no longer find the webhooks button (goto project > little gearwheel on the right > webhooks). Its literally not there anymore.

When running `gitlab-rake gitlab:web_hook:list` on the terminal I can still see the 17 webhooks that I set. **How can I get the webhooks button back?**

**additional information**:
Gitlab is running on a Ubuntu server 16.04 (lts) system. Gitlab reports to be healthy and all services are running according to the web interface. Restarting gitlab did not help.

**versions**:

GitLab 8.16.3

GitLab Shell 4.1.1

GitLab Workhorse v1.3.0

GitLab API v3

Git 2.10.2

Ruby 2.3.3p222

Rails 4.2.7.1

PostgreSQL 9.2.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webhooks are now located under Integrations. Project > little gearwheel on the right > Integrations.

Comment: I searched for an hour for this...Thanks ;)